# How to pass variable of adding 270 days to the date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my query:

```
select 
  facility_lob as FACILITY_LOB,
  TO_DATE(REPLACE(posting_d_date_sk, ',', ''), 'YYYYMMDD') as PostingDate,
  count(distinct encounter_num ||cast(date_of_service as varchar(20) )) as ENCOUNTER_VOLUME,
  SUM(charge_amt) as Gross_Charges 
from sources.Table 
where 1=1 
and REPLACE(posting_d_date_sk, ',', '') >= '20210101' 
and REPLACE(posting_d_date_sk, ',', '') <= '20210928'
and posting_d_date_sk <> '-1' 
and posting_d_date_sk  is not NULL 
group by facility_lob, posting_d_date_sk 
order by REPLACE(posting_d_date_sk, ',', '')
```

For now, I have hard coded the dates from Jan 1, 2021 to Sep 28, 2021 ( which is 270 days from Jan  1, 2021).

My requirement is the query should should pull data from  and greater than year 2021 (>= 2021 of the posting date), and I need to pull the data from Jan 1, 2021, to 270 days. If I run the query today, I need to get the data from Jan 1, 2021 to Sep 28 2021 ( which is 270 days from jan 1 2021). If I execute this query tomorrow, I need to get the data from Jan 2 2021 to Sep 29 2021. jan 3, 2021 to sep 30 2021 etc.. If I run the query on April 3, 2022 then the calculation of 270 days is from Feb 1, 2021, to Oct 29, 2021.

Could you please help how do I fix this?

Comment: sorry only postgres. i removed redshift tag.

Comment: Why don't store dates as date? If you do so, you can use + en - to do some calculations on dates. Maybe you need an interval, maybe you don't.

Comment: Below is the sample record: Below is the format of date

NEO  2021-01-01 213    274082.0000

Comment: What is the logic behind using date range for today is 01-Jan - 28-Sep and for 3rd april - 01-Feb - 29 Oct.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a simple dateadd based on getdate and then format it into your format ?

```sql
Declare @to varchar(10), @from varchar(10), @mydate smalldatetime 

Set @mydate = Getdate()
Set @from = convert(varchar,year(@mydate)) + right('0' + convert(varchar,month(@mydate)),2) + right('0' + convert(varchar,day(@mydate)),2)

Set @mydate = dateadd(dd,270,getdate())
Set @to = convert(varchar,year(@mydate)) + right('0' + convert(varchar,month(@mydate)),2) + right('0' + convert(varchar,day(@mydate)),2)
```

Comment: This is SQL Server Syntax not postgres syntax.

Comment: Sorry didn’t realise that you need postgres syntax

Comment: Indeed you can transform my syntax using postgres : SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day';